# ClassNotFoundException in Websphere Liberty Profile for properties placeholded thru @Value annotation

Tags: java, spring, classnotfoundexception, websphere-liberty

I am facing a strange problem ;-)

There is some attributes in our application that are placeholded thru @Value spring annotation. When the application is launched we receive a ClassNotFoundException for the property key config.bpm.authorize_tasks_no_group :

```
------Start of DE processing------ = [1/13/16 11:20:12:295 CET]
Exception = java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
Source = com.ibm.ws.jndi.internal.WASURLObjectFactoryFinder.findFactory
probeid = 74
Stack Dump = java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jndi.url.config.bpm.authorize_tasks_no_group.config.bpm.authorize_tasks_no_groupURLContextFactory
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.UnifiedClassLoader.findClass(UnifiedClassLoader.java:118)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.UnifiedClassLoader.loadClass0(UnifiedClassLoader.java:106)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.UnifiedClassLoader$Delegation.loadClass(UnifiedClassLoader.java:77)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.UnifiedClassLoader.loadClass(UnifiedClassLoader.java:101)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.ThreadContextClassLoader.loadClass(ThreadContextClassLoader.java:110)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at com.ibm.ws.jndi.internal.WASURLObjectFactoryFinder.findFactory(WASURLObjectFactoryFinder.java:63)
    at org.apache.aries.jndi.ContextHelper.getURLObjectFactory(ContextHelper.java:102)
    at org.apache.aries.jndi.ContextHelper.createURLContext(ContextHelper.java:69)
    at org.apache.aries.jndi.DelegateContext.getURLContext(DelegateContext.java:248)
    at org.apache.aries.jndi.DelegateContext.findContext(DelegateContext.java:214)
    at org.apache.aries.jndi.DelegateContext.lookup(DelegateContext.java:161)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate$1.doInContext(JndiTemplate.java:155)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:87)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:152)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:179)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorSupport.lookup(JndiLocatorSupport.java:95)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorDelegate.lookup(JndiLocatorDelegate.java:38)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorSupport.lookup(JndiLocatorSupport.java:77)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorDelegate.lookup(JndiLocatorDelegate.java:33)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiPropertySource.getProperty(JndiPropertySource.java:82)
    at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:84)
    at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:60)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractEnvironment.getProperty(AbstractEnvironment.java:511)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer$1.getProperty(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:135)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer$1.getProperty(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:132)
    at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:84)
    at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getPropertyAsRawString(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:70)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver$1.resolvePlaceholder(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:207)
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:147)
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:204)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:178)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer$2.resolveStringValue(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:175)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveEmbeddedValue(AbstractBeanFactory.java:801)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:434)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:2389)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer31.osgi.webapp.WebApp31.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp31.java:503)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:1049)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:6448)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost.startWebApp(DynamicVirtualHost.java:446)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost.createRunnableHandler(DynamicVirtualHost.java:248)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost.createRunnableHandler(DynamicVirtualHost.java:313)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.internal.VirtualHostImpl.discriminate(VirtualHostImpl.java:251)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.ready(HttpDispatcherLink.java:306)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:470)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:404)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:284)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:255)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:174)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:83)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java:504)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java:574)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java:929)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java:1018)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any idea ?

Eric

Comment: replace `config.bpm.authorize_tasks_no_group` to `config_bpm_authorize_tasks_no_group`

Comment: do you actually have a class called `com.sun.jndi.url.config.bpm.authorize_tasks_no_group.config.bpm.authorize_tasks_no_groupURLContextFactory`?  Seems like this is the property name and the value is not getting read properly.  (agreeing with what @user1516873 said)

Comment: The problems is solved now, I don't know why...